# Get CHANGETABLE changes for one user

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

**Context:**

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and it's CHANGETABLE module to keep multiple databases (SQlite) in sync with the online server running (SQL Server 2008)

**Solution Chosen:**

I generate queries from the results that CHANGETABLE returns.
ex:

idAccount | SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION

1        |           U

will give me "Update Accounts set idAccount = 1, .. WHERE idAccount = 1"

This system works fine if you want a full copy of the database

however the problem is that it will download all the accounts for all users and all other information relative to other users.

What I want to be able specify an idUser so that I can get just the information for ONE user.

**The Problem** is that userId is not in every table. I'd like to avoid queries like :

```
SELECT CT.idAccount,SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION
FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES Accounts, 0) AS CT
WHERE CT.idAccount IN (
    SELECT m.idAccount
    FROM Marketing m 
    WHERE m.idMarketing  IN (
        SELECT idMarketing
        FROM another_table
        WHERE userId IN(
            SELECT userId
            FROM Users u
            WHERE userId = 1
        )

    )
)
```

I hope I was clear enough, any ideas on how to get all the changes for one user without doing queries like the one abow?

Comment: Why not make it so that all systems use the same database? Any reason you keep multiple databases with the same data? Just looks like allot of avoidable maintenance and performance problems to me.

Comment: the other databases are on mobile devices to be able to support an offline mode

Comment: Sounds like a valid reason, perhaps consider the possiblity to give not only the userId as a parameter but also idAccount? Perhaps as a table valued parameter. Also EXISTS then to be faster as IN

Comment: this is just an example, in reality the only table that allows you to filter by user is the userId

Comment: thanks for the tip concerning EXISTS and IN